# UILabel on UIImageView transparency weird behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel, transparency

i'm working on an apps, and i have the following problem (see the picture).

my backgroundview color is black.
on this view, i'have a imageview with alpha at 0.5

```
  _backgroundImageView.alpha = 0.5;
```

and on this imageView i have a label, a button and another image, but i dont why all the content on my imageview are a little bit transparent, i dont want it like that.

i tried to set alpha to 1 of all my content on my imageview, but i dont works ....

maybe somebody have a idea ?

here my view organization :
[image]

here my apps
[image]

**UPDATE**
i tried this, but still no work :
_poiDetailsView is the view how contain my uiscrollview.

```
   _poiDetailsView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
```

i tried this too :

```
  [_backgroundImageView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1]];
```

Comment: If you want your views to be composited before alpha is applied, add `UIViewGroupOpacity == YES` to your info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Superview's alpha is always set on the subviews, no matter how you set it up manually.

One way of overriding this odd behavior is to use the [colorWithAlphaComponent](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/colorWithAlphaComponent:) for subviews which are colored, but I'm not sure if it can be done for images as well.

If you reorganize your views so that the subviews are inside a different view laid over, rather than being a subview, of your view with low alpha, you'll avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your views to be composited before alpha is applied, add `UIViewGroupOpacity == YES` to your info.plist

Answer (score 0):

i solve my issue with the following line :

```
_poiDetailsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


_backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"burritos"];

[_backgroundImageView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
_backgroundImageView.alpha = 0.5;
```

Without add UIViewGroupOpacity in .plist. it works good like that, just dont forget to set as default the backgroundcolor in storyboard.

have a nice day.